# Combine two files and put data next to each other in C

Tags: c

This code is a combination of two text files

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
  FILE *movieyear;
  char year[90];
  movieyear = fopen("Lecture 07 - Movie Data - Year.txt", "r");
  FILE *moviedata;
  char data[90];
  moviedata = fopen("Lecture 07 - Movie Data - Releases.txt", "r");
  FILE *NEWdata;
  char DData;
  NEWdata = fopen("Movieinfo.txt", "w");
  if (movieyear == NULL || moviedata == NULL) {
    printf("Error opening file\n");
    return (-1);
  }
  if (NEWdata == NULL) {
    printf("Error opening file\n");
    return (-1);
  }

  while ((DData = fgetc(movieyear)) != EOF) {
    fputc(DData, NEWdata);
  }
  while ((DData = fgetc(moviedata)) != EOF) {
    fputc(DData, NEWdata);
  }

  fclose(movieyear);
  fclose(moviedata);
  fclose(NEWdata);
  return 0;
}
```

This text file writes in:

```
2015
2019
2009
2018
2018
1997
2015
2012
2017
2018
Star Wars: Episode VII - The Force Awakens
Avengers: Endgame
Avatar
Black Panther
Avengers: Infinity War
Titanic
Jurassic World
Marvel's The Avengers
Star Wars: Episode VIII - The Last Jedi
Incredibles 2
```

My desired result:

```
Star Wars: Episode VII - The Force Awakens 
2015
Avengers: Endgame 
2019
Avatar 
2009
Black Panther 
2018
Avengers: Infinity War 
2018
Titanic 
1997
Jurassic World 
2015
Marvel's The Avengers 
2012
Star Wars: Episode VIII - The Last Jedi 
2017
Incredibles 2 
2018
```

Comment: Fix your code indentation.

Comment: Is there an error or is this more helping you code?

Comment: @Will: It's a logic error.

Comment: Step 1: `char DData;` --> `int DData;`

Comment: @chux has taken the time and effort to re-format your code for you.  Notice how much easier it is to read?  This should be the *first* thing you do, not the last.

Comment: Sorry this is my first time really posting on here. I’ll make sure to to be more mindful next time.

Comment: It's not because of the rules of the site.  It's because your code becomes readable.

Comment: Please learn to write code and do the indentation at the some time. Will make your life a little easier

Comment: Also it is a good idea to check the return values from functions. eg. `fopen` can return null

Answer (score 1):

This

```
while((DData = fgetc(movieyear)) != EOF){
    fputc(DData,NEWdata);
}

while((DData = fgetc(moviedata)) != EOF){
    fputc(DData,NEWdata);
}
```

Will quite clearly output all of the years first, and then all of the titles.

What you need is a single loop that will output both the year and the title at the same time.

Comment: I’ve tried to combine it but I’m still having trouble. I don’t know where to combine it at

Comment: Well, you could try filling those year and data arrays, and using those.  At the moment, they're just sitting there unused.

Comment: Should it replace DData with the corresponding arrays?